# Trying to create custom bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a custom bootstrap navbar as shown in the following image:[image]

What I have used is a usual bootstrap `navbar-default` and made following changes in the css:

```
 .navbar-default{
  margin-top:50px;
  background:transparent;
  border:none
} 
/* 
.nav>li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

li.active{
  border-top:3px solid red;
   padding-top:60px

}

 */
 li.active div.abc{
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    height: 56px;
    position: relative;
    width: 56px;
    top: -20px;
 }

 li.active a{
    padding-top: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

 li.active a:visited{
   color:green
 }
```

The `div.abc` that you can see above in css code is something that I am adding dynamically through jQuery. Whenever some link gets clicked, I am setting its `class` to `active` and `wrapping` `div class="abc"` to the `a` tag inside of `li`. 
Following jQuery code will make it more clearer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $('.navbar-nav li').on('click',function(){

                        $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');

                        $(this).addClass('active');

                        if($(this).find("div")){
                            //if div inside of li, dont do anything             
                        }        
                        else{
                             $(this).find('a').wrap('<div class="abc"></div>');
                        }

        })

                $('.navbar-nav li.active').find('a').wrap('<div class="abc"></div>');

})
```

The image that I have attached above is only showing the behaviour on the first link. But I want the same behaviour in link **that gets clicked**. Currently the behaviour is pretty messy when I click on other links.

Attaching the fiddle also so as to make more clearer as to what I have achieved so far:https://jsfiddle.net/anzrv6fw/1/

Appreciate any help!!!

Comment: This line of code `if($(this).find("div")){` change it to `if($(this).find("div").length){` will work, However your code is too messy, do clean it up and recode of the use of `div.abc`.

Comment: That works a bit. But I want to unwrap the `div` when some other link is clicked. How can I do that? I tried usin `unwrap` jquery but was unable to acieve the same.@nstungcom

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer finally.

Added these two lines to jQuery and it worked:

```
var cnt=$('.navbar-nav li div.abc').contents();
$('.navbar-nav li div.abc').replaceWith(cnt);
```

Thanks anyone who saw the post and tried to help.